# What is this plastic handle that is used for corn and watermelon called?

Tags: equipment

I've seen these plastic handle things and searched for phrases like the one in the question title but failed to find it. What are they called? And where can I get buy them from?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're just called [corn holders](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_11?url=search-alias%3Dgarden&field-keywords=corn%20holders&sprefix=corn+holder%2Cgarden%2C334&rh=i%3Agarden%2Ck%3Acorn%20holders), or corn skewers. I've never seen them holding watermelon before. As a matter of fact, they don't seem to me to be appropriate for watermelon. I don't see how they would make watermelon easier to eat and they're quite sharp. Especially for a kid, that seems kind of *dangerous*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems dangerous to me too, now that I think more carefully about it! Good point.

Comment: As far as where to buy them - local kitchen supply stores should carry them, and there appear to be dozens of options available on Amazon.  Those in your photos look like the Zyliss brand.